# Are there two types of negatives? Or why is there no symmetry between + and -?

Tags: logic

The short question is: we generally take it that, it doesn't matter what we "name a thing". It is what it is no matter how we name it (such as in Tao Te Ching). So how come if we name one thing △, then △△ = △, but if we name it ▢, then ▢▢ is not ▢ but is △?

Say, we we take `+` and the opposite of `-`, like `+` is going to the right on the x-axis, while `-` is going to the left of the x-axis, everything is fine so far.

Now note they are opposite, and one is taken to be positive, and one is taken to be negative, just like Yin and Yang.

But what if it is `left` and `right` as the Yin and Yang?  Consider `(-1) x (-1)`, it gives you `+1`, or `-(-1)`, it also gives you `+1`, but what about `(+1) x (+1)`?  Why doesn't it gives you the symmetry of giving you `-1`?  The same with `+(+1)`.  Why doesn't it give you `-1`?  That is, if `+` and `-` are just in two different directions, then, say, you put the chart on the table.  The person sitting across the table, will now see the `+` as `-`, and see `-` as `+`.  So to me, if `-` `-` can get the opposite: the `+`, why can't `+` `+` get the opposite: the `-`?  Because to the person sitting across me at the table, my `-` is his `+`.

This may explain it more: if you say `left` `left` should give `right`, then why `right` `right` will not give `left`?  Because if I stand facing north, versus a person facing south, then my `left` is his `right`.  Then my `left` `left` giving `right`, to him, is `right` `right`, giving `left`, but to me, it is `right` `right` giving `right` (just like `+(+1)` is `+1`.  So why it is not symmetric?

I suppose one easy argument may be, because `-` is to "negate" something and therefore `-` and `+` are different, but this doesn't explain, what about `left` and `right`?  Then how can we define what is the `negate`?  What I see going left, the other person sees it as right, so if left is negate, then he will say, no, the direction you are pointing at, is "right" and it is not negate.  If I say, `that direction` `that direction` (`-` `-`) will give the opposite (`+`), and he will say, no, `that direction` `that direction` (`+` `+`) WILL NOT give the opposite.  Why is that?

P.S. I am asking this question because if math is one way of describing properties in the universe, then we hold it true and accurate that `-` `-` gives a `+`, but `+` `+` gives a `+`.  On the other hand, we have a philosophy that you can name one direction one thing, be it left or right, left can be right if another person sees it at a different angle, and we can name one direction as positive or name it as negative, and if you were to do calculations, everything still work as expected.  So if these two philosophies, or ideas, or notions are true and accurate, why do they seem to contradict each other?  (because if you name it `△`, then `△` `△` will give you `▢`.  But if you name it `▢`, then `▢` `▢` will give you `▢`.  Supposedly, how you name it shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Not sure you why you wrote it but this is **not** "just like Yin and Yang". Moreover, there's nothing really philosophical about your question. It's more a kind of math puzzle question.

Comment: I vote for reopen. Even when the post mixes a series of different concepts, the core question is clear: Why are +1 and -1 not symmetrical with respect to multiplication? I tried to give an answer.

Comment: I do agree with virmaior.  You will have an easier time understand the (correct) answer of jo Wehler if you do not think of positive and negative as yin and yang.  On the surface, both are "opposites," but if you look any deeper than the surface, you find that the relationship between yin and yang is quite entirely unlike the relationship between positive and negative in mathematics.

Comment: I tried to understand as a quest of knowledge, or as a love of knowledge. Or to understand the universe. I am even trying to not talk too much about math, as the universe can run without a single person talking about math.

Comment: @JoWehler I agree there's an answerable question here (and I think you have the right answer), but how is the question *about philosophy*?

Comment: ＠太極者無極 ...  That's a weird comment considering the majority of your question is about math.

Comment: @virmaior I consider the philosophical content of  太極者無極而生  's question comparable to the philosophical content of some of Plato's thoughts about numbers.

Comment: One approach may be to think of negation as a mirror, switching the chirality of things.  If you reflect something once in a mirror, left and right are swapped, but if you reflect it twice, left and right return to their normal state.  This can be repeated any number of times (not just 0 1 or 2 reflections), so we can reasonably say that left and right will be swapped after 31 reflections.

Comment: I put how this relates to philosophical thinking into the P.S.

Comment: In response to the PS: you wrote "we can name one direction as positive or name it as negative, and if you were to do calculations, everything still work as expected" this is not true, any more than I can name a dog as a "duck," and then feel confused that it doesn't fly.  WHen you say "works as expected," I believe the behaviors you are considering are all additions.  It should not be a surprise that when you go to multiplication, things don't always work out.  There's a reason why mathematics has addition and multiplication as *different* operators, not the same operator.

Comment: If I was not careful with your logic, I could argue that since I carry a briefcase through the airport, and a terrorist carries a bomb to his target, both carrying relationships "work as expected," so thus I should be able to call myself a terrorist and call my briefcase a bomb.  Needless to say, if I were to make this foolish assumption anywhere near airport security, I would not be answering stack exchange questions today.  Just because a small set of relationships "work as expected" does not imply that all relationships must work.

Comment: @CortAmmon No, did you study math or physics yourself?  You could use meter as the unit and everything should work. Or you could use feet, or inch, and things will not become "weird".  Any math or physics teacher will tell you that you can set your axis positive going to the right hand side, or you can set it to be negative going to the right hand side -- you just have to make sure now going to the left, it is considered as positive now.  I do not know what it is about you want to make addition become multiplication

Comment: So what you have shown is that negation does not work like yin and yang, units, or right and left.  It is something different; it acts differently.  The reason I bring up addition and multiplication is that all of the examples you are using work very well for addition, but they start to break down in multiplication, and multiplication is the only case where -1 * -1 = 1.  One thing that might help to clarify: are you seeking to approach negation as a fundamental facet of reality itself, or are you seeking to understand its place as a tool we use to understand the reality around us?

Comment: We may be able to better help knowing what you would like to achieve with your line of reasoning.

Comment: @CortAmmon as I said, it is the quest of knowledge, or the love of knowledge.  There is nothing I'd like to achieve, or you can say, to achieve the quest of knowledge

Comment: From your conversation, and looking at Jo's answer, my best recommendation for the next step on such a quest would be to develop a familiarity with the mathematical concept of rings.  As for your question, the answer is simple.  It's the one Jo gave: the behavior you see is simply how rings operate in mathematics, case closed.  I do believe there are more "quest of knowledge" questions that can follow, especially those relating to why a ring is "useful" enough concept in the first place to have been identified and explored by mathematicians, but it will be easier for others to help you ...

Comment: ... in your quest if you become familiar enough with the concepts and terminology to phrase the next question in terms of the vernacular of mathematics.  Mathematics has a lot of *truth* to it.  There's little truths around every turn (it depends on it).  The more precise your wording is, the easier it is to direct our attention to the portion of the truth you are interested in seeking.

Comment: "Negative" in multiplication just means "go in the opposite direction." The opposite of an opposite is the original. The original (+) is also the original. I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: as I said, I don't understand why there is no symmetry

Comment: @太極者無極而生 maybe the reason is that yin and yang are inherently asymmetrical, and this manifests itself in the asymmetry of (some properties of) multiplication; intuitively, I think it works that way because systems aren't isolated, and some system "nearby" tends to leak in; the nearby system is caused by, and at the same time gives rise to, the asymmetry; in yin and yang philosophy, this asymmetry is the energy of life. (I'm not a professional philosopher, so this is just my fuzzy intuition)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I think in a way asking why multiplication works like that, is like asking why yin and yang work the way they do  — a question whose answers all possibly contain more questions like that... which I think doesn't mean we shouldn't look for these answers, or that they are not useful, because they might lead one to intuitively grasp the fractal pattern, or smth...

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone has developed a number system with such symmetry.

Comment: "* if you say left left should give right, then why right right will not give left?*" -- Two wrongs don't make right, but three lefts do.  Left and right each behave just like -1, but instead of having a cycle of length 2, they have a cycle of length 4.

Comment: @RayButterworth I am saying if you name it Left, then Left Left gives you Left. If you name it Right, then Right Right gives you Left.

Answer (score 1):

The role of +1 and -1 in mathematics is best understood when considering the set of integers including zero. Integers (***Z***,+,*) form a ring with respect to addition and multiplication. Integers have to distinguished elements:

1. The neutral element of addition is 0:

> x + 0 = 0 for all x from ***Z***

Any x has an inverse -x with respect to addition, i.e. x + (-x) = 0. Hence with respect to addition, x and -x are symmetric.

2. The neutral element concerning multiplication is 1:

> x * 1 = x for all x from ***Z***, in particular 1 * 1 = 1

The same does not hold for -1. Hence 1 is a distinguished element concerning multiplication, but -1 is not. There is no symmetry between 1 and -1 concerning multiplication.

From 1 + (-1) = 0 follows be multiplying both sides by (-1) and applying elementary rules:

(-1) * 1 + (-1) * (-1) = (-1) * 0

-1 + (-1) * (-1) = 0

(-1) * (-1) = 1, q.e.d.

Comment: I really am not looking for a "proof" that `(-1) x (-1)` is `1`.  I am asking why there is no symmetry, as in the PS: "if you name it △, then △ △ will give you ▢. But if you name it ▢, then ▢ ▢ will give you ▢. Supposedly, how you name it shouldn't matter" just like if you name a duck as woofie, the duck is still a duck and will not bark

Comment: @太極者無極而生  You ask why there is no symmetry between +1 and -1? - What about changing the view and asking: Is there any reason to assume that +1 and -1 are symmetrical? Then the answer is: No, there is no reason. Because +1 is a distinguished number concerning multiplication and -1 is not a distiguished number.

Comment: maybe I am not asking for "symmetry". I am asking why when we call ▢ as ▢, then ▢▢ is ▢, but if we name it △, then △△ is ▢. What we name it shouldn't matter. If we name a duck as "woofie", do you think the duck will morph into something else?

Comment: @nopole It's not an issue of naming. There are two distinct objects +1 and -1. They are distinct because they have different properties.

Comment: a point in the universe, it is the same exact point. Person A can set a coordinate system (say, even just one dimensional) and label that point +1. Person B can use a different coordinate system and that point becomes -1. Without knowing Person A and B exist, Person C looks at the point, is it ▢▢ = ▢ or is it ▢▢ = △  Or can you say, there is nothing absolute. You need Person A or B's coordinate system to set as a reference to "make it absolute". (absolute only possible if referenced to something). Maybe I can accept it. But Einstein said there is something absolute in the universe...

Comment: But Einstein said there is something absolute in the universe... and that's the speed of light.  And so, maybe even speed of light is not absolute then?  Nothing is absolute in the universe? Except the sentence "Nothing is absolute in the universe", which is absolute?

Comment: @nopole The discussion has now moved far away from your original question. -  According to General Relativity there are physical quantites which are independent from the choice of a coordinate system, e.g., the speed of light and also the scalar curvature. In this sense you may call these invariants "absolute".

Comment: actually, it is all related to my original question